# Restarting UIActivityIndicator on keystroke

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

If I remember correctly before I upgraded to Swift 3, the following code worked to achieve the look of the spinner starting at 0 progress again for each stroke. I'm looking for the exact same effect Instagram uses in their searching.

```
   spinner.stopAnimating()
   spinner.startAnimating()
```

It used to just completely refresh the spinner. Now, it's just pausing the spinner for a millisecond while you're typing then continuing on. Looks very jittery.

I've got "hides when stopped" checked, and I've tried adding some spinner.hidden = true/false in there respectively to stopping/starting, that also did not work.

Any idea what got changed/ what I need to do to regain the effect?

Answer (score 0):

Changing it's view style causes it to reset it's animation:

```
spinner.stopAnimating()
spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle=UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.white
spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle=UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
spinner.startAnimating()
```